# Java BigDecimal data converting to opposite sign long

Tags: java, type-conversion, precision, bigdecimal, truncation

According to the Java 7 [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#longValue()), the method **longValue** from class **java.math.BigDecimal** can return a result with the opposite sign.

> Converts this BigDecimal to a long. This conversion is analogous to the narrowing primitive conversion from double to short as defined in section 5.1.3 of The Java™ Language Specification: any fractional part of this BigDecimal will be discarded, and if the resulting "BigInteger" is too big to fit in a long, only the low-order 64 bits are returned. Note that this conversion can lose information about the overall magnitude and precision of this BigDecimal value as well as **return a result with the opposite sign**.

In what case is it possible?

Comment: It can happen "if the resulting "BigInteger" is too big to fit in a long," and the top bit of the last 64 bits is `1`.

Comment: Let's say the integer part of the `BigDecimal` would take 75 bits to represent. That's too big to fit into a `long`. As the documentation says, in this case, only the lowest 64 bits are put into the `long`. If the highest of those 64 bits happens to be 1, the number will be negative.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is possible whenever the value of the `BigDecimal` is larger than what a `long` can hold.

Example:

```
BigDecimal num = new BigDecimal(Long.MAX_VALUE);
System.out.println(num);                  // prints: 9223372036854775807
System.out.println(num.longValue());      // prints: 9223372036854775807

num = num.add(BigDecimal.TEN);            // num is now too large for long
System.out.println(num);                  // prints: 9223372036854775817
System.out.println(num.longValue());      // prints: -9223372036854775799
System.out.println(num.longValueExact()); // throws: ArithmeticException: Overflow
```

Answer (score 2):

I will happen if the value is greater than the max value of long

```
BigDecimal dec = new BigDecimal(Long.MAX_VALUE +1);
System.out.println(dec.longValue());
```

Comment: `Long.MAX_VALUE + 1` is `-9223372036854775808`, so the `BigDecimal` will have the value `-9223372036854775808`, and `longValue()` will return the *exact* value, without overflow.